# Searching by category name in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

With the wordpress default search form/funtionality, when I search by a category name, it doesn't show any result whereas there are several posts under the category. For example, if there's a category 'France' with a subcategory 'Paris', a post that is associated with both categories does not appear in search results if I search either by France or Paris - except if these 'words' are used within the post title or content.

I'm looking for a way to display related posts in search results when a category name is searched.

Here is the search form I'm using:

```html
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform form-elements" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <div class="text-box">
        <label for="s">Enter keyword...<?php _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ); ?></label>
        <input class="input" type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
    </div>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ); ?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: where is the query used for search?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the WordPress default function wp_dropdown_categories().

By default WordPress search function searches on post name or title.

Your code should be

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform form-elements" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <div class="text-box">
        <label for="s">Enter keyword...<?php _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ); ?></label>
        <input class="input" type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
    </div>
    <div class="text-box">
        <label for="search_category">Category:</label>
        <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'name=search_category' ); ?>
    </div>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ); ?>" />
</form>
```

I use `wp_dropdown_categories()` and `name="search_category"`

You can use [wordpress Relevanssi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/) Plugin for modify category searches.